# How can I write a Nokia application with pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, nokia

I have seen questions on my Facebook group about 'Can I write Nokia apps with pyqt', but no one has answered. I am curious, can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

You might like to look at http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Getting_started_with_PyQt_for_Maemo,

Because of issues with PyQT being available only for GPL applications without money, Nokia released their own Python/QT bindings:  http://developers.slashdot.org/story/09/08/30/0823206/Nokia-Makes-LGPL-Version-of-PyQt

Most Nokia development is still done in C++.  Nokia provides a free IDE for this route.